# Trigonometric Identities HW

Tags: trigonometry

Learning trigonometry right now.

I have a question that asks:

> Write the trigonometric expression in terms of sine and cosine, and
>   then simplify:
>
> $$(\cot^2\theta + 1) \sin^2\theta$$

I know the answer is $1$. I'm confused on how to get there.
I have:

$$(\cot^2\theta+1)\sin^2\theta = \csc^2\theta\sin^2\theta$$

Comment: Could you let us know how far you have got, and where you are getting stuck?

Comment: OK - do you know the definition of $\csc$?

Comment: Because I have a sheet of identities. cot^2θ+1 = csc^2x

Comment: That is not the definition of $\csc$ that I use! Do you know a definition of $\csc$ in terms of $\sin$?

Comment: cscx = 1/sinx   ?

Comment: Yes - can you finish the problem using that?

Comment: WOAH, thank you very much. Is there a way to give you points? I use stackoverflow to help me in programming and trig is the first wall I've hit learning math. I know if you give an answer, I can confirm it.

Comment: No worries - I don't need points. Glad to help.

Comment: One other question:

I have to simplify:
sinx cos^2 x + sin^3 x

My guess is that it becomes sin^2 x. But it's marked wrong. I used the pyhtagorean identity of sin^2 x + cos^2 x = 1 to get there.

Comment: Take out a factor of $\sin x$: to get $\sin x \cos^2 x + \sin^3 x = \sin x (\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x) = \sin x (1) = \sin x$. If you get any more, maybe drop into the chatroom?

Comment: Lol that seemed so obvious looking at it now. I'll see how far I get.

Comment: @OldJohn While you may not want reputation points for helping munchschair, it would still be good to get this out of the unanswered queue. I recommend either munchschair answers it themself or you answer community-wiki, and either way munchschair accepts it.

Comment: Gotta say math.stackexchange is a lot friendlier then stackoverflow. People aren't very big on letting things like formatting slide on nubes. Thanks ya'll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question in your main post, you are nearly there:

$$(\cot^2\theta+1)\sin^2\theta = \csc^2\theta\sin^2\theta$$

and now just use the definition that $\csc\theta = 1/\sin\theta$ to get:

$$\csc^2\theta\sin^2\theta = \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}.\sin^2\theta = 1$$

For the question in the comments:

$$\sin x \cos^2 x + \sin^3 x = \sin x (\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x) = \sin x . (1) = \sin x$$